# Can a flexible flue liner be installed in an old central heating flue for modern HVAC systems?

Tags: gas, central-heating

I have an old gas central heating system which has recently failed. Newer systems cannot leverage the old flue as they require an internal pipe as well. 
Replacing the flue will cost a considerable amount of money. I was wondering if there is an option where a composite 'rubbery' pipe can be thread through the old flue thus not requiring me to swap out the entire flue.

Comment: I don't think so. If there was, don't you think the installer would have offered that?

Comment: Why does it need to be "rubbery"? Can't a rigid pipe be fitted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a flexible metal flue liner can often be installed in an old masonry flue. In fact, I had one done last year, where we had an old (wood-burning) fireplace and installed a gas-fired log fireplace insert. The contractor threaded the two flexible pipes down from the top -- one for combustion air and one for venting the exhaust.  Many modern boilers also have the option to use a sidewall power-vent, which doesn't need any flue at all -- just some PVC pipes.

There are numerous suppliers of flexible metal chimney-liners.